# Why is my render image appearing with the image and a white background ? Should be transparent PNG

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, transparency, glass

I am looking to render a transparent png logo in Cycles. The logo I have is made with a low poly glass material and I have transparent and transparent glass selected in Film. I have attached pictures of my output settings and my view plus the rendered image (with white background).

Any assistance would be so helpful !!

[image: render image (white background)]
[image: camera viewport shading]
[image: filmsettings]
[image: output settings]

Comment: Maybe an object is set to visible for render, check the Outliner, if it's not the case, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Also check your compositing nodes.